# Which Portuguese language to be learned when moving to Angola, Luanda

Tags: language-comparison, portuguese

I will be moving to Angola, Luanda very soon. I have heard that the  spoken language of Luanda is Portuguese which is different from Portugal-Portuguese. So which language do you suggest to learn **Angolan-Portuguese** or **Portugal-Portuguese.**

I have been using a an android app **Learn Portuguese** for the moment. By the way I love Portuguese language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.quora.com/Is-Angolan-Portuguese-closer-to-Brazilian-Portuguese-or-Portugal-Portuguese

The general consensus here is that Angolan Portuguese is closer to European Portuguese as far as pronunciation. It shares other vocabulary and grammar with both European and Brazilian Portuguese. Also, highly educated Angolans' Portuguese is even more similar to the European variety. Of course, this makes sense. Angola has a historical connection to Portugal. There may have been some migration from Angola to Brazil via the slave trade, but not the other way around.